# Julia dataframe directly access row

Tags: dataframe, julia

In Julia DataFrames it is possible to directly access a column `:col` of a dataframe `df` by writing `df[!, :col]`. Is it a similar fast way to directly access a row? I know I can do `df[2, :]` to get a copy of row 2, but I don't want a copy since I want to change the content of the row.

Cheers Sigurd

Answer (score 8):

Selecting a single row from a data frame returns a `DataFrameRow`, which is a [view of the row](https://juliadata.github.io/DataFrames.jl/stable/lib/types/#DataFrames.DataFrameRow) in the original data frame. So any changes you make to the `DataFrameRow` will be reflected in the original data frame:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(a=1:3, b=4:6)
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ a     │ b     │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 4     │
│ 2   │ 2     │ 5     │
│ 3   │ 3     │ 6     │

julia> dfr = df[2, :]
DataFrameRow
│ Row │ a     │ b     │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 2   │ 2     │ 5     │

julia> dfr.b = 100
100

julia> df
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ a     │ b     │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 4     │
│ 2   │ 2     │ 100   │
│ 3   │ 3     │ 6     │
```

Of course, if you just want to change the values of a few entries in a row, you can do that directly without having to first create a `DataFrameRow`:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(a=1:3, b=4:6)
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ a     │ b     │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 4     │
│ 2   │ 2     │ 5     │
│ 3   │ 3     │ 6     │

julia> df[2, :] = [101, 102]
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 101
 102

julia> df
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ a     │ b     │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 4     │
│ 2   │ 101   │ 102   │
│ 3   │ 3     │ 6     │
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was confused since it didn't work with the `!` operator. I aso see that my question was poorly phrased. What I want to do is to get the row or rows `df[(df.a .== 2) .& (df.b .== 5),:]` and change them.I guess I can just use eachrow to iterate over the rows and change the ones that fit my criteria.

Comment: Yeah, `eachrow` is a good option. It's also possible that, depending on your application, you don't need to worry much about copying the data. For example, if you do something like `newdf = @transform(df, c = 2 * :b)`, where `@transform` is from [DataFramesMeta.jl](https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFramesMeta.jl), it will return a new data frame. But it will probably be fast enough for many data manipulation activities. And of course treating your data as immutable is easier to reason about and helps avoid bugs.